# Access variable from other workspace in Matlab?

Tags: function, matlab, scope, workspace

Is there something similar to `assignin()` to fetch a variable which exists in another workspace and get it to the local workspace, e.g. like accessing a base-workspace variable in a function!?

One example I'm currently trying to achieve is: I have a function `bla(x)` which takes one parameter. When `x` isn't being specified, the function should automatically use the `x` which exists in the base matlab workspace (if there is a `x`).

Something nice would be

```
function bla(x)
  if(nargin == 0 && exist('x', 'base', 'var'))
    x = fetchin('base', 'x');
  end

  % ...
end
```

I know that `fetchin()` doesn't exist and that `exist()` doesn#t take such a second parameter to check in a certain workspace!
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Matlab function [`evalin`](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/techdoc/ref/evalin.html) can do that:

```
x=evalin('base','x');
```

EDIT: As mentionned by Col Heather, you could use a try / catch statement to handle the errors that could be generated by the function `evalin` (in your case if the variable does not exist for example) and then check if the variable has the correct type.

Comment: Ahh that's what meant by 'execute expression'. I thought this would be only for calculations, but yes you are right! Calling the expression `x` just gives the values of `x`. Thanks. Is the above a good approach to simplify the call of the function for the user but still give him the possibility to pass his own values (just in case he needs to call it from elsewhere)? What happens when there is NO `x`? How to check this before calling `evalin`?

Comment: What if your user's `x` is not called `x`?

Comment: I make sure for that :-) To get rid of the existence-check I came up with the idea to simply use `if(nargin == 0), try, x=evalin('base','x'); catch err, error('Either the workspace var x must exist, or you need to pass x to the function'); end, end`

Answer (score 2):

Checking for variable existent in caller/base can be done via:

```
   existStr=sprintf('exist(''%s'', ''var'')==1', varNames{iVar}); % verify variable exists
    isVarExist=evalin(ws, existStr);
    if isVarExist
        valVar=evalin(ws, varNames{iVar});
    else
        valVar=[];
    end
```