# Matlab navigate function workspace

Tags: matlab, function, workspace

I am looking for a way to access variables from other workspaces, in particular the workspace from which the current function is called.

*I know how to do it in the simple case*:

```
% Get a variable called `x` from the base workspace
x = evalin('base', 'x');
```

---

*However*, think of a [situation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18765323/983722) where my function `myFun`, is called by many different functions (which I cannot edit). And I just know that each of them will have a variable `x`.

Now, how would I be able to see the variable `x` from the workspace in which `myFun` is called?

So I guess the key point in my question is:

**How can I programmatically navigate to the above workspace?**

---

*Here is how it can be done manually*:

1. Set a breakpoint
2. Once the breakpoint is hit use `dbup`
3. Find x and look at it (or do something with it (with `evalin` or `save`/`load` for example)
4. Hit f5

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access variable from other workspace in Matlab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8572177/access-variable-from-other-workspace-in-matlab)

Comment: Related, and the title would suggest it, but after reading that question and answer (which is pretty much already included in this question) I don't think it is a duplicate.

Comment: IMO that's basically the same question, except having the `'base'` workspace instead of the `'caller'` workspace, as in your case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
x = evalin('caller', 'x')
```

There is a limitation however, from Matlab's documentation:

> evalin cannot be used recursively to evaluate an expression. For example, a sequence of the form evalin('caller','evalin(''caller'', ''x'')') doesn't work.

However, `evalin` is not a great function. Any usage should be avoided imho.

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I missed this. Do you think there is a way to get anything between the base and the caller? Or get a list of workspaces?

Comment: You can use `dbstack` to get a list of workspaces, however it is not possible to go access those with `evalin`.